# r.thin (GRASS) not giving correct result

Tags: grass-gis, vectorization, raster-to-point

[image]

I have raster image of road feature. I want to extract line feature from it. So I run r.thin tool on it of parameter -

```
{ 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'input' : 'C:/Users/User/Music/test111.tif', 'iterations' : 200, 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
```

and then r.to_vect. But the result of r.thin is giving one or two yellow pixels.

[image]

What is wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRASS r.thin command require a NULL/non NULL raster. In your raster probably there are no null cells, so all cells are considered as part of the line, so the result looks correct. First you should set black(0) pixels to null using `r.null`, it is also available in processing toolbox in the GRASS group. I downloaded your image to show you the steps.
[image]

Then you can use the `r.thin` command on the result of `r.null`.

[image]

Finally use `r.to.vec`

[image]

Here are the results of the steps for the upper left corner of your image:

[image]

Probably you had better to use Douglas-Pecker simplification on the result of `r.to.vec` using `v.generalize`.

Comment: Yes it works. Many thanks.